# Extract numbers and operators from a String

Tags: java, string, numbers, expression, extract

This is the code I made:

```
public static boolean isOperator(char op){
    if (op == '+' || op == '-'
            || op == '*' || op == '/'
            || op == '^'
            || op == '(' || op == ')'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isOperand(char op){
    String numbers = "0123456789.";
    int a = numbers.indexOf(op);
    return a >= 0;
}
public static void main(String []args){        
    String exp= "15+20+(3.84*25)*(78/3.8)";
    LinkedList a = new LinkedList();

    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++){
        if (isOperator(exp.charAt(i))){
            a.add(exp.charAt(i));
        } else if (isOperand(exp.charAt(i))){
            int k = i;
            while (k < exp.length()){//I see the length of the number
                if (isOperand(exp.charAt(k))){
                    k++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k != exp.length()-1){//if it's not ad the end
                a.add(exp.substring(i, k));
            } else {//if it's at the end I take all the remaining chars of the string
                a.add(exp.substring(i));
            }
            i = k-1;//i must go back since the subtring second parameter is exclusive
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(a);    
}//main
```

This is the output:

```
[15, +, 20, +, (, 3.84, *, 25, ), *, (, 78, /, 3.8), )]
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. As you can see I put operand and operators separately into a list maintaining the order of the string.
There is a way to do it in a simpler way?

Comment: This looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AR89 check my solution, i hope it is the one you look for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it in a simpler way?

Yes, there is. Use **regular expressions**. Take a look at the following code and
try to run it for your inputs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String exp = "15+20+(3.84*25)*(78/3.8)";
    String regex = "(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)])";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(exp);

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(m.group());
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

*Explanation of my regex used above:*

"(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)])"

(double) or (integer) or (arithmetic operator) or (left/right paranthesis)

Comment: I added the '^' operator to you regular expression: String regex = "(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([+-/*///^])|([/(/)])";

Answer (score 2):

The best way of doing such parsing jobs would be to use Parser generators. However, if you want to do it yourself, you have a number of alternatives. In this case, you could also do it in this way:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
      String exp = "15+20+(3.84*25)*(78/3.8)";
      LinkedList<String> a = new LinkedList<String>();

      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(exp, "+*/-()", true);
      while(st.hasMoreTokens())
          a.add(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Comment: From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead._